# Flying with Swiss Economy class (W) - what is my luggage allowance?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, legal, swiss, fare-class

I am flying with Swiss on Economy class (fare code W). My ticket says that my luggage allowance is no check-in luggage and one piece of hand-luggage. However, [the Swiss website says that I have the right to an extra piece of hand luggage](https://www.swiss.com/gb/EN/prepare/baggage/hand-baggage), in the form of a

> Handbag, laptop bag or shoulder bag (max. 40 x 30 x 10 cm)

Which is my real baggage allowance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The website states it:

In addition to your one piece of hand luggage your allowed to:

> Adults and children with their own seats may also take the following on board:
>
> ```
> Handbag, laptop bag or shoulder bag (max. 40 x 30 x 10 cm)
> Child's seat
> One pair of crutches, arm or leg splints, other kinds of prostheses
> Medical equipment
> ```

So you can take an additional handbag, or laptop bag with you. Be careful that it's not over 8 Kilogram. Most often this rule is not enforced with Swiss, but recently when I had a small but 19 Kilogram handbag, I had to convince the airline staff that they allowed me to take it with my as hand luggage.

Comment: FYI I say airline staff weighing carry-ons with a portable scale just before boarding. The overweight ones were forced to be checked-in at the gate. I managed to sneak past this check, and this was a necessary manoeuvre since I had no checked-in luggage allowance on my fare.

Comment: Since 2019, the hand luggage weight and size limitations are quite strictly enforced on LX short haul flights, depending on the departing airport. Also, important to note is that if you have a high enough status with M&M, you have additional allowance.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, a handbag, laptop bag etc. doesn't count as hand luggage, but is often also called "personal item". So you still have one piece of hand luggage, and the additional personal item.